# Date range validation with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, assert

I want to add a constraint with annotation in Symfony for a date falls within the range, but this range can not be specified explicitly with min. and max. The year should be between the current year (by subtracting the current year or number) and the minimum indicated. For example, if I type a date now must be between 2010/1960, but 2010 should be obtained from the current year-10. This can be done in any way in Symfony?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, read more in the cookbook: ["How to Create a custom Validation Constraint"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Comment: have a look at this, you can modify the validate method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972404/symfony2-validation-datetime-1-should-be-before-datetime-2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony2 Validation Datetime 1 should be before Datetime 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972404/symfony2-validation-datetime-1-should-be-before-datetime-2)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you should create a custom validation constraint as explained here :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html