# How can I use the bootstrap-daterangepicker in symfony 3.4?

Tags: symfony, daterangepicker

I try with the next code:

In the form builder

```
->add('daterange', DateType:class, array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'attr' => ['class' => 'js-daterangepicker'],
   'html5' => false,
))
```

And the javascript

```
$('.js-daterangepicker').daterangepicker({
});
```

This code works, but retrieve data invalid as validator result.
Is DateType the class? How do I recover the selected data in the widget?

Comment: I think you must develop a custom validator for that. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185153/date-range-validation-with-symfony2

Comment: Have a look to : http://blog.michaelperrin.fr/2013/03/20/range-date-validator-for-symfony2/